# How can i store cube method

Tags: perl

I want to store an ini file of data. How can I store cube method in perl.

I tried:

stylesheet.ini:

```
p   indent  noindent
h1  heading1
h2  heading2
h3  heading3
h4  heading4
h5  heading5
h6  heading6
disp-quote  blockquote
```

Script:

```
my %stylehash;
open(INI, 'stylesheet.ini') || die "can't open stylesheet.ini $!\n";
my @style = <INI>;
foreach my $sty (@style){
      chomp($sty);
      split /\t/, $sty;
      $stylehash{$_[0]} = [$_[1], $_[2], $_[3], $_[4]];
}

print $stylehash{"h6"}->[0];
```

Here I assign $*[2], $*[3], $_[4] unwanted arrays place in. because first P tag will be get two arrays and then h1 get one array. How can I store perfectly and how can I retrieve it.

I need:

```
$stylehash{$_[0]} = [$_[1], $_[2]]; #p tag
$stylehash{$_[0]} = [$_[1]]; #h1 tag

print $stylehash{"h1"}->[0];
print $stylehash{"p"}->[0];
print $stylehash{"p"}->[1];
```

how can I store cube method. Tag is always unique and style name randomly increase or decrease. How can I solve this problem.

Comment: What exactly is 'Cube Method'?

Comment: my %cube = ('$_[0]', [$_[1], $_[2]], '$_[0]', [$_[1]],); here I will example, $_[0] are uniq keys, but values are different size of arrays, I can't store directly above ini file. I can retrive easly but I can't store diff size of arrays for each keys.

Comment: The feature where `split` assigns its results to `@_` in void context is deprecated. Use with caution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a bunch of keys with lists of values.  Maybe one value, maybe two, maybe three... and you want to store this.  Simplest thing to do is to build this into a hash of lists and use a pre-existing data format like [JSON](https://metacpan.org/module/JSON) which handles Perl data structures well.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use JSON;

# How the data is laid out in Perl
my %data = (
    p     => ['indent', 'noindent'],
    h1    => ['heading1'],
    h2    => ['heading2'],
    ...and so on...
);

# Encode as JSON and write to a file.
open my $fh, ">", "stylesheet.ini";
print $fh encode_json(\%data);

# Read from the file and decode the JSON back into Perl.
open my $fh, "<", "stylesheet.ini";
my $json = <$fh>;
my $tags = decode_json($json);

# An example of working with the data.
for my $tag (keys %tags) {
    printf "%s has %s\n", $tag, join ", ", @{$tags->{$tag}};
}
```

More on working with [hashes of arrays](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-ARRAYS).